# how to export function with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I intend to bundle all my .js using webpack.
I tried with a very simple example as following.

Function to bundle in a test.js file :

```
function test() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Webpack configuration :

```
module.exports = [{
  {
    output: {
      filename: 'test.js',
      path: __dirname + '/public/javascript/dist'
    },
    entry: [
      './public/javascript/test.js'
    ]
  }
]
```

Code to test :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <script src="./javascript/dist/test.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{
    test();
}

</body>
</html>
```

But I receive the following error : Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined.

Question : why?

[Edit] Reponse is : "export" is missing.
Thanks to that, I updated as following:

Code to export :

```
export function Test() {
  this.t = 1;

  Test.prototype.toto = function()
  {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

Webpack conf :

```
{
output: {
  filename: 'test.js',
  path: __dirname + '/public/javascript/dist',
  library: 'test',
  libraryTarget: 'window'
},
entry: [
  './public/javascript/poc/test.js'
]
}
```

To create the object, I have to do : var t = new test.Test();
It's a bit heavy... Is there a way to only have to make : var t = new Test(); ?

Comment: are you sure webpack emits your js file? are you sure that all paths are correct? have you checked the console for errors? too little information.

Comment: Why don't you accept Yury Tarabanko answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> why?

Because you haven't exported anything from your entry point and, by default, webpack generates output in umd format without polluting global scope.

You first have to export your function:

```
export default function test() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Then specify "library" and "libraryTarget" in your webpack config. [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library). For example:

```
output: {
  filename: 'test.js',
  path: __dirname + '/public/javascript/dist',
  library: 'test',
  libraryTarget: 'window',
  libraryExport: 'default'
},
```

this will generate code that adds `window.test = _entry_return_.default` .

Comment: Using export keyword is not mandatory to bundle files with webpack

Comment: Much better. I only use "export function test() ..." to make it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Since webpack 5 you're able to export to a variable instead of binding methods to the global `window`.

So when you are exporting your function like so:

```
export default function test() {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

And configure the library type to `var` (`libraryTarget` in earlier versions of webpack 5):

```js
output: {
  filename: 'test.js',
  path: __dirname + '/public/javascript/dist',
    library: {
      name: 'myLibrary',
      type: 'var',
    },
  }
```

You can access your method like so:

```js
myLibrary.test()
```