# React - Reuse components from external bundle files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I have two very basic `React` app's that I bootstrapped using `create-react-app`. The first app exports a very simple `button` component. I want to bundle my first react app using `Webpack` and then in my second react app, I want to bring the `button` component into use. Any pointers on how I go about doing this?

I did look at other questions asked, but I have not been able to make any of them work.

Comment: do you mean "app2 imports complete bundle made of app1 and use only some component(s)"?

Comment: @skyboyer as a first pass, yes, import the complete bundle and then use only some component. I have code splitting in mind, but I want to start with very basic use first. Just to get my feet wet with how this works.

Comment: check this article, I believe it should help https://itnext.io/how-to-package-your-react-component-for-distribution-via-npm-d32d4bf71b4f

Comment: I'm afraid this way things would become much more complicated than if you moved your reusable component into separate package from the start

Comment: and here is about exporting from withing webpack bundle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817227/how-to-export-function-with-webpack

Comment: @skyboyer What if I don't want to `npm package` my app1? I am thinking `micro-frontends` and I want each front-end to be served as bundle that consuming app's can chose to pick from. Putting it very simply, what if I was to serve up two *micro-frontends* as a bundle each and my consuming app, uses a `script` tag or something to pull the necessary bundle down and then use the front-end component that the bundle is exporting out.

Comment: Why not just import the bundled JS file from App 1 into App 2?

Comment: @Adam, well, that is what I am trying to achieve. What mechanism do I have to achieve that? Any pointers or examples? Imagine that App 1 and App 2 are two different teams working on two different repos. App 2 is a feature that App 1 will consume.

Comment: It depends on how you have the app(s) setup locally. If both apps are stored locally at known locations, just export the button component in App 1 (through the entry file specified in `package.json`) and then `require` App 1 in App 2. Could you provide the directory structure of both apps and where they're located if possible?

Comment: @Adam i am not sure how I will achieve that using `require`. On my localhost, both apps are running on different ports. I understand, I can export my `button` component through my entry file. But how does the consuming App 2 know where to `require` App 1 from? Sorry if I seem a little lost here.

Comment: Let's say App 1 is at `C:\App1`, so it's main file might be `C:\App1\index.js` which exposes the button component via `export`. Then in App 2, you could say `const Button = require('C:/App1')`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok I see what you were suggesting. Even if this works how do I scale this for something that is not running on my laptop? @Adam

Comment: Using Node, you can place App1 into the `node_modules` directory of App2 and use `const Button = require('App1')` in the App2 code. That way the require path is relative no matter where your apps are.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can do `npm install` with git repo instead of name. It does not need publishing your packages(so for your "main app" you can just run `npm install` with URL to micro-frontends that should have package.json created)
2. In your `package.json` you need to describe main file.
3. Main file will re-export some specific components you will be able to reuse later.
4. In your "main application code" you import and use components from bundle as usual.

I'm not 100% sure if it's crucial but I'd also list React/other libs as 'peerDependencies' not 'dependencies' in package.json of micro-frontend's bundle

[UPD] have realized that this would not work in case there are different frameworks used. Since all the parts are React-based in your case then approach above should work. But I agree it's definitely not really micro-frontend way