# How do I save a txt file from a React app into a SilverStripe 4 back end?

Tags: reactjs, silverstripe-4

I have a react-app nested inside a SilverStripe 4 project. I am trying to integrate the react-app correctly within SilverStripe project so that files the react-app creates can be saved into SilverStripe back end. The way it is nested is similar to the solution provided for this question:

[How to insert (inject?) an existing React app (just a UI without a backend) into a SilverStripe page layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737585/how-to-insert-inject-an-existing-react-app-just-a-ui-without-a-backend-into)

The react-app creates a graph and has a save button which takes the information from the graph and creates a txt file which can then be saved to my local system. In addition to this I want the save button to send the txt file into an appropriate table in the SilverStripe project (which wraps the react-app).

Currently I am learning the SilverStripe framework and you can see I have not yet got anything in my page controller that would help me do this. Any suggestions on what I might need are greatly appreciated.

Below are the methods in the react-app that locally save and load a txt file:

```
  saveJson = () => {
    const validJson = this.state.json;
    window.localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY, validJson);
  };

  loadJson = () => {
    const json =
      window.localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY) ||
      JSON.stringify(this.state.High, null, 2);
    this.setState({ json });
  };

...

 dataToSave = () => {
    let data = {};
    data.High = this.checkStateArrayForData("High");
    data.Intermediate = this.checkStateArrayForData("Intermediate");
    data.Low = this.checkStateArrayForData("Low");
    data.Output = this.checkStateArrayForData("Output");
    data.Input = this.checkStateArrayForData("Input");
    data.links = this.state.links;
    return data;
  };

...

 onReaderLoad = event => {
    let obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
    let time = new Date().getTime();
    this.setState({
      High: obj.High,
      Intermediate: obj.Intermediate,
      Low: obj.Low,
      Output: obj.Output,
      Input: obj.Input,
      linksToRender: obj.links,
      time: time
    });
  };
```

Below is the code from the return method that relates to the Save button

```
 render() {
    const uri =
      "data:text/json;charset=UTF-8," +
      encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.dataToSave(), null, 2));

...

return(
...

  <input
                type="file"
                id="file"
                ref={ref => (this.upload = ref)}
                style={{ display: "none" }}
                onChange={this.onChangeFile}
                accept=".txt"
              />
              <ToolbarItem
                icon="ic-open"
                label="Open"
                onClick={() => {
                  this.upload.click();
                }}
              />
              <a href={uri} download="myfile.eval">
                <ToolbarItem icon="ic-save" label="Save" />
              </a>
```

Below is the ToolbarItem component as the save button is a ToolbarItem component. Note: I have inherited this code which is a prototype written by someone else. I think this component should be functional and not have a state.

```
import React from "react";

class ToolbarItem extends React.Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        return <div className="item" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            <div className={`icon ${this.props.icon}`}></div>
            <div className="label">{this.props.label}</div>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default ToolbarItem;
```

Below is the SilverStripe page layout:

```
<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="content">   
                    <div class="main col-sm-12" 
                         style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"> 

                            <div id="root">
                                If you can see this your React app hasn't initialised yet
                            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

Below is my SilverStripe class for the react-app:

```
<?php
namespace SilverStripe\Lessons;

use Page;    
use SilverStripe\Assets\File;

class ReactAppPage extends Page 
{
  private static $table_name = 'example5_ReactAppPage';
  private static $has_one  = [
      'svg' => File::class,
      'woff' => File::class,
      'woff2' => File::class,
      'ttf' => File::class,
      'eot' => File::class,
    ];
}
?>
```

Below is the page controller for the react app:

```
<?php
namespace SilverStripe\Lessons;

use SilverStripe\View\Requirements;

use PageController;    

class ReactAppPageController extends PageController 
{
    protected function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        // Build files for the react-app. NOTE: Doesn't include media folder files which are manually placed in a SilverStripe-app/public/static/media folder.
        Requirements::javascript('app/react-app/build/static/js/main.40bb7a47.js');
        Requirements::css('app/react-app/build/static/css/main.ca3832cb.css');

    }
}
?>
```

The expected results would be that after the user hits the save button in the react-app, they will then be given the option of where they want to save the file (locally or in SilverStripe back end). If they choose SilverStripe back end the file will automatically save to a table in the SilverStripe database.

Thank you for your time reading. Please comment if you notice missing information. I will be editing this question as I continue to research how to do this and will use the comments to find answers. Cheers :-)

Comment: An idea received in relation to this question that I am currently trying to implement is as follows: "set up a Form on an SS Controller that receives the data you want to send, POST your data to that endpoint from the React app. The only catch is that you would need to pass a SecurityID (CSRF measure) with the request, so you would have to make sure the React app has access to that, by loading it in to the initial page response perhaps, or fetching one on submit in your React app prior to submitting the SS Form request."